# Check whether specific radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm having trouble after looking at the jQuery docs.  I'm just trying to return true/false in one my my jquery methods depending on the check of a certain radiobutton and if it's selected or not

I've tried several things but have not been able to get this right:

```
<input type="radio" runat="server" name="testGroup" id="test1" /><label for="<%=test1.ClientID %>" style="cursor:hand" runat="server">Test1</label>
<input type="radio" runat="server" name="testGroup" id="test2" /><label for="<%=test2.ClientID %>" style="cursor:hand" runat="server">Test2</label>
<input type="radio" runat="server" name="testGroup" id="test3" /> <label for="<%=test3.ClientID %>" style="cursor:hand">Test3</label>
```

and in my method I have this:

```
return $("input[@name='test2']:checked");
```

I'm getting an undefined on `$("input[@name='test2']:checked");`

UPDATED:

example:

```
<input type="radio" runat="server" name="radioGroup"  id="payPalRadioButton" value="paypalSelected" />
```

this returns 'undefined' still:

```
$("input[@name=radioGroup]:checked").attr('payPalRadioButton');
```

If I try this, I get 'false' even if I select the radio button:

```
$('input:radio[name=radioGroup]:checked').val() == 'paypalSelected'
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Your selector won't select the input field, and if it did it would return a jQuery object. Try this:

```
$('#test2').is(':checked');
```

Comment: it's returning false every time even though I select lets say test2

Comment: Dear God .NET forgot about the unique random clientID it creates for ID.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're using the wrong approach. You should set the `value` attribute of your input elements. Check [the docs for .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for examples of setting and returning the .val() of input elements.

ie.

```
<input type="radio" runat="server" name="testGroup" value="test2" />

return $('input:radio[name=testGroup]:checked').val() == 'test2';
```

Comment: well I can't go and change all that now.  That would require a lot of refactoring on our current page.

Comment: regex for the win! Just replace your ids with values. Point is, input elements (especially check boxes and radio buttons) should have a value. More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Comment: $('input:radio[name=bar]:checked').val(); so we don't have value in there I suppose that defaults then to 0,1, and 2 respectively

Comment: That may be, but I'm not sure you can rely on it. See the w3.org documents I linked -- `value` is optional except when the type attribute has the value "radio" or "checkbox".

Comment: I still get false per your example when I select the button

Answer (score 4):

1.You don't need the `@` prefix for attribute names any more:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/:

> Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style
>   selectors were removed (they were
>   previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2).
>   Simply remove the ‘@’ symbol from your
>   selectors in order to make them work
>   again.

2.Your selector queries radio buttons by `name`, but that attribute is not defined in your HTML structure.

Comment: well name would be the same for all 3 radiobuttons since it's a group in this case.

Comment: exactly, it IS the same, but you still need it there

Comment: I have name...so not sure what the problem is?? :(

Comment: the problem is `name='test2'` -- the name of your radio group is actually `testGroup`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the '@' before 'name'; it's not needed anymore (for current jQuery versions).

You're want to return all checked elements with name 'test2', but you don't have any elements with that name, you're using an **id** of 'test2'.

If you're going to use IDs, just try:

```
return $('#test2').attr('checked');
```

Comment: I'm still getting an undefined..it doesn't know what #test2 is.

Answer (score 0):

WHy bother with all of the fancy selectors? If you're using those id="" attributes properly, then 'test2' must be the only tag with that id on the page, then the .checked boolean property will tell you if it's checked or not:

```
if ($('test2').checked) {
    ....
}
```

You've also not set any values for those radio buttons, so no matter which button you select, you'll just get a blank "testGroup=" submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[@name='<%=test2.ClientID%>']:checked");
```

use this and here ClientID fetch random id created by .net.

Comment: Question is asked before 6 years..and s/he also get answer..you can't say `use this`

Answer (score 0):

Just found a proper working solution for other guys,

```js
// Returns true or false based on the radio button checked
$('#test1').prop('checked')


$('body').on('change','input[type="radio"]',function () {
alert('Test1 checked = ' + $('#test1').prop('checked') + '. Test2 checked = ' + $('#test2').prop('checked') + '. Test3 checked = ' + $('#test3').prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" runat="server" name="testGroup" id="test1" /><label for="<%=test1.ClientID %>" style="cursor:hand" runat="server">Test1</label>

<input type="radio" runat="server" name="testGroup" id="test2" /><label for="<%=test2.ClientID %>" style="cursor:hand" runat="server">Test2</label>

<input type="radio" runat="server" name="testGroup" id="test3" /> <label for="<%=test3.ClientID %>" style="cursor:hand">Test3</label>
```

and in your method you can use like

```
return $('#test2').prop('checked');
```