# Find out whether radio button is checked with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, checked

I can set a radio button to checked fine, but what I want to do is setup a sort of 'listener' that activates when a certain radio button is checked.

**Take, for example the following code:**

```
$("#element").click(function()
{ 
    $('#radio_button').attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

it adds a checked attribute and all is well, but how would I go about
adding an alert. For example, that pops up when the radio button is checked
without the help of the click function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check of specific radio button is checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195125/check-of-specific-radio-button-is-checked)

Comment: related `Monitoring when a radio button is unchecked` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824639/monitoring-when-a-radio-button-is-unchecked

Answer (score 1198, accepted):

```
$('#element').click(function() {
   if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
});
```

Comment: Bingo! thanks David. So would I have to invoke an action (click etc) to show the alert? Is there a way to do this without clicking?

Comment: well, you could run the `is(':checked')` check whenever. so if you want to show something on page load, depending on whether a checkbox is checked, for instance, you can just put the same if statement in page load.

Comment: This doesn't solve the "without the help of the click function", does it?

Comment: @Znarkus: OP appears satisfied. would you argue that you own use of `('#radio_button').click` is without `click`?

Comment: I thought he was refering to his click function. If OP has tested your solution and it works for him, all is good :)

Comment: Please also add explanation as to where should others add their code. So which fields to substitute in this with what?. Thanks

Comment: @David Second line should be `if ($('#radio_button').is(':checked'))) { alert("it's checked"); }` - you forgot the jQuery $ sign and then need to wrap it all in some more parenthesis.

Comment: @zua: you're right! it even had a syntax error, the way it was before (unmatched brackets). fixed

Comment: "So would I have to invoke an action (click etc) to show the alert? Is there a way to do this without clicking?" - Okay, I know this is kinda old, but this might help others. If you want to invoke it without using click event, you can use document ready event.

Answer (score 178):

If you have a group of radio buttons sharing the same name attribute and upon submit or some event you want to check if one of these radio buttons was checked, you can do this simply by the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit_button').click(function() {
    if (!$("input[name='name']:checked").val()) {
       alert('Nothing is checked!');
        return false;
    }
    else {
      alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
    }
  });
});
```

[Source](http://lostwithin.net/check-if-a-radion-button-is-checked-using-jquery/)

[jQuery API Ref](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: This did not work for me. If I 
alert($("input[@name='shipping_method']:checked").val()); it still gives me the value even if the radio button is not selected.

Comment: Note: If you have several forms with groups of radio buttons using the same name, you need to make sure to check only those of the form that is submitted. One option to do this is using the find method on the form: 
`$('#myform').submit(function(event){
if (!$(this).find("input[name='name']:checked").val()) {`

Answer (score 54):

As Parag's solution threw an error for me, here's my solution (combining David Hedlund's and  Parag's):

```
if (!$("input[name='name']").is(':checked')) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
else {
   alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}
```

This worked fine for me!

Answer (score 38):

You'd have to bind the click event of the checkbox, as the change event doesn't work in IE.

```
$('#radio_button').click(function(){
    // if ($(this).is(':checked')) alert('is checked'); 
    alert('check-checky-check was changed');
});
```

Now when you programmatically change the state, you have to trigger this event also:

```
$('#radio_button').attr("checked", "checked");
$('#radio_button').click();
```

Answer (score 28):

//Check through class

```
if($("input:radio[class='className']").is(":checked")) {
     //write your code         
}
```

//Check through name

```
if($("input:radio[name='Name']").is(":checked")) {
         //write your code         
}
```

//Check through data

```
if($("input:radio[data-name='value']").is(":checked")) {
         //write your code         
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Another way is to use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) **(jQuery >= 1.6)**:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
    if($(this).prop("checked")) { alert("checked!"); }
});
```

Comment: Indeed `.prop()` is much faster, and simply easier to type.

Answer (score 13):

The solution will be simple, As you just need 'listeners' when a certain radio button is checked. Do it :-

```
if($('#yourRadioButtonId').is(':checked')){ 
// Do your listener's stuff here. 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Working with all types of Radio Buttons and Browsers**

```
if($('#radio_button_id')[0].checked) {
   alert("radiobutton checked")
}
else{
   alert("not checked");
}
```

[Working Jsfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LLc86nmr/)

Answer (score 8):

... Thanks guys... all I needed was the 'value' of the checked radio button where each radio button in the set had a different id...

```
 var user_cat = $("input[name='user_cat']:checked").val();
```

works for me...

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want a click function
use Jquery change function

```
$('#radio_button :checked').live('change',function(){
alert('Something is checked.');
});
```

This should be the answer that you are looking for.
if you are using Jquery version above 1.9.1
try to use on as live function had been deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

**ULTIMATE SOLUTION**
**Detecting if a radio button has been checked using onChang method**
JQUERY > 3.6

```
         $('input[type=radio][name=YourRadioName]').change(()=>{
             alert("Hello"); });
```

**Getting the value of the clicked radio button**

```
 var radioval=$('input[type=radio][name=YourRadioName]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 4):

dynamic generated Radio Button Check radio get value

```
$("input:radio[name=radiobuttonname:checked").val();
```

> On change dynamic Radio button

```
$('input[name^="radioname"]').change(function () {if (this.value == 2) { }else{}});
```

Answer (score 4):

$('.radio-button-class-name').is('checked') didn't work for me, but the next code worked well:

```
    if(typeof $('.radio-button-class-name:checked').val() !== 'undefined'){
     // radio button is checked
    }
```

Comment: Since your used it with a class instead of an ID, it would have returned a nodelist, instead of an element. `$('.radio-button-class-name').first().is(':checked')` should have worked.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is still popular, but if you want to have no dependencies, see below.
Short & clear function to find out if radio button is checked on ES-2015:

```js
function getValueFromRadioButton( name ){
  return [...document.getElementsByName(name)]
         .reduce( (rez, btn) => (btn.checked ? btn.value : rez), null)
}

console.log( getValueFromRadioButton('payment') );
```

```html
<div>  
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="offline">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="online">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="part" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="free">
</div>
```

Comment: When I tryed to run your code snippet here in stack overflow iIt seems not working as a test , could you edit it so we can easily try it .However It seems working on my project and very clear thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    if($('input[name="radiobutton"]:checked').length == 0) {
        alert("Radio buttons are not checked");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work in all versions of jquery.

```
//-- Check if there's no checked radio button
if ($('#radio_button').is(':checked') === false ) {
  //-- if none, Do something here    
}
```

To activate some function when a certain radio button is checked.

```
// get it from your form or parent id
    if ($('#your_form').find('[name="radio_name"]').is(':checked') === false ) {
      $('#your_form').find('[name="radio_name"]').filter('[value=' + checked_value + ']').prop('checked', true);
    }
```

your html

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
var checked_value = 'checked';
  if($("#your_form").find('[name="radio_name"]').is(":checked") === false) {
      $("#your_form")
        .find('[name="radio_name"]')
        .filter("[value=" + checked_value + "]")
        .prop("checked", true);
    }
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="your_form">
  <input id="user" name="radio_name" type="radio" value="checked">
        <label for="user">user</label>
  <input id="admin" name="radio_name" type="radio" value="not_this_one">
    <label for="admin">Admin</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alert($('#radiobutton')[0].checked)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$("#radio_1").prop("checked", true);
```

For versions of jQuery prior to 1.6, use:

```
$("#radio_1").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: This *sets* the value of the `checked` property, instead of querying it.