# How to know if radio is checked

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out if radio button is checked with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272507/find-out-if-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery)

Hi, i want to make a div appear with jquery when one of 3 radio buttons is pressed..

I have 3 radio buttons, image video and sound, when the user clicks image, a div will appear.

how can i use jquery for this. I know how to do the div appearing part, just not the checking if the specific radio button is checked.

Bascially, how do i check if a specific radio is checked.

Thanks

Comment: +1 wish more people would search and vote to close....so many duplicates on here now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$('#radioButton').get(0).checked
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if($('#radioButton').is(':checked')){
    //radio button with id 'radioButton' is selected
    //your logic here
} else {
   //radio button is not selected
   //your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#radioButton1').attr('checked')) {
    // show div 1, hide div 2 and div 3
} else {
    if($('#radioButton2').attr('checked')) {
        // show div 2, hide div 1 and div 3
    } else {
        if($('#radioButton3').attr('checked')) {
            // show div 3, hide div 1 and div 2
        }
    }
}
```