# get value from radio group using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I am trying to get value of radio group with name `managerelradio`. My html code for this radio group is.

```
 <label><input type="radio" name="managerelradio" value="Yes" id="Add">Add</label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="managerelradio" value="No" id="Remove">Remove</label>
```

and Jquery for this is..

```
    var manageradiorel = $('input[name = "managerelradio"]:checked' , '#managechildform').val();
 alert(manageradiorel);
```

its showing me undefined.

Though I have also tried it as.

```
 var manageradiorel = $('input[name = "managerelradio"]:checked').val();
 alert(manageradiorel);
```

But still I am getting undefined value.

Comment: Can you post HTML too? .That will help us to understand the problem

Answer (score 152):

Try this

```
var manageradiorel = $("input:radio[name ='managerelradio']:checked").val();
alert(manageradiorel);
```

Plese check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/afMZc/3/) DEMO ..it will work fine

**Note:**  One of your radio button must be selected. Otherwise it will return undefined

You can use `checked` attribute to make a radio button selected as default

Comment: also it must be placed in onchange event, i guess

Comment: @Shameer, I dont think so . You can see the demo

Comment: It works for me (even without onchange event), this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: +1, works. For the case of not having more than one button group, one can leave the name specification in the selector away.

Comment: It would be nice if jQuery was smart enough to figure out that `$("#managerelradio").val()` as looking for the value of the *radiobutton group*, but since it isn't that smart, at least there's logic in the construction of this selector...

Answer (score 17):

It works for me

```js
$('input[name="managerelradio"]').on('change', function(e) {

    var manageradiorel = e.target.value;
    alert(manageradiorel);

});
```

Exaple [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/ms5BC/)

Comment: Though its work if I use change function on radio group but it won't work if I put in some other change function like on drop down change.

Comment: @Rahul: Your one of your radio button must selected to get the value.review my update here[link](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/ms5BC/)

Answer (score 10):

A small jQuery extension to make this a little easier:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    groupVal: function() {
        return $(this).filter(':checked').val();
    }
});

// Usage:
$("input[name='managerelradio']").groupVal();

// Or even:
$("[name='managerelradio']").groupVal();
```