# how to fetch value from 2 radio buttons in JavaScript after form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

i have a form with 2 pair of radio buttons i want to fetch the value on form submission in jquery. **this code is working fine for single radio button but i dont know how to fetch the value of genderkid the 2nd radio button?**

where to add name field in the code???

```
<form onsubmit="return chk()">
father<input type="radio" name="gender"/>
mother<input type="radio" name="gender"/>
boy<input type="radio" name="genderkid"/>
girl<input type="radio" name="genderkid"/>
</form>
<script>
function chk(){
**var gender = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();**
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does it help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723505/get-value-from-radio-group-using-jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var gender = $("[name=gender]:checked").val();
var genderkid = $("[name=genderkid]:checked").val();
```

OR

```
var gender = $("input:radio[name=gender]:checked").val();
var genderkid = $("input:radio[name=genderkid]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
var gender = $("input[name=gender]:checked").val();
var genderkid = $("input[name=genderkid]:checked").val();
```

Also please give value attribute for your radio inputs:

Ex:

```
<input type="radio" value="boy" name="genderkid"/>
<input type="radio" value="girl" name="genderkid"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below code snippet...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function chk(){
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        var gender =$('input[name=gender]:checked', '#myForm').val()
        alert(gender);
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="return chk()">
        father<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>
        mother<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>
        boy<input type="radio" name="genderkid" value="boy"/>
        girl<input type="radio" name="genderkid" value="girl"/>
        <input type="submit"/> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for get **multiple radio button values with different attribute names** in jquery

```
<form onsubmit="return chk()">
father<input type="radio" name="gender" value="father"/>
mother<input type="radio" name="gender" value="mother"/>
boy<input type="radio" name="genderkid" value="boy"/>
girl<input type="radio" name="genderkid" value="girl"/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="chk()"/>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
function chk(){
$("input:radio").each(function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    if (this.checked) {
        var src = $this.attr('name');
        var val = $this.val();
    alert(val);

    }

});
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/thcLS/1/)