# Perform an action when radio button choice is toggled

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a form with radio button in bootstrap, such that whenever a radio button is toggled, a different form with new fields should appear subsequently:

```
<tr>
 <td><label for="exampleInputEmail3" class="input-group">1 or 2 ? </label></td>

       <td>
         <select id="whatever" name="whatever" class="input-group">

         <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" />one<br />
         <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" />two<br />>
         </select>
      </td> 
</tr>
```

If user selects option 1, form 1 needs to be displayed just below it otherwise form 2 needs to be shown.

The form 1 looks like:

```
<tr id="whatever_description">
<td><label for="exampleInputEmail3" class="control-label">1</label></td>
</tr>
```

The form 2 looks exactly the same with different label:

```
<tr id="whatever_description">
<td><label for="exampleInputEmail3" class="control-label">2</label></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You're making a bootstrap form with `<tr><td>` ..? ohkay. So where's the html for the forms to be displayed..? are we also supposed to make that for you..?

Comment: Edited. I hope I am clearer.

Comment: -1 please no tables for layout in 2014

Comment: k, but I think it was necessary in my case. Btw, my question is in different context, why are you guys so much into 'tr' and 'td'?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery to do this easily.
First you can use the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to get the value of the radio button you checked.
Then you can use the [hide/show](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) functions to show the right form and hide the other.
I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need different ID's for your table rows.  Two elements cannot share the same ID.  You can listen for changes with the `change` function and then toggle the visibility of both rows at the same time by using the comma to grab multiple selectors and then show/hide each respectively with `toggle`

```
$('input[name="radioName"]').change(function () {
    $("#whatever_description1, #whatever_description2").toggle();
});
```

#### [Here's a demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AF2zV/)

---

If you want more control, see [get value from radio group using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7723505/1366033)