# Toggle show/hide based on multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, radio-button, conditional-statements, toggle

I'm working on showing a specific div when multiple radio buttons are selected. I can make it work when I just have 1 condition (radio value equals X), but I need it to make "IF radio1 equals X AND radio2 equals A)

I've tried multiple ways, but this one seems the one with most potential, as I don't need to hide all other possibilities, as happens with other scripts I've tried.

```
<script type="javascript">
$(function() {

/* Code that works for 1 condition (show div named 1A with FirstSelector value is 1) */

    $('input[name=FirstSelector]').change(function() {
      $("div[name=1]").toggle(this.value === "1")
    }).filter(":checked").change()

    $('input[name=FirstSelector]').change(function() {
      $("div[name=2]").toggle(this.value === "2")
    }).filter(":checked").change()

/* Code for multiple IFs that is not working */

    $('input[name=FirstSelector]').change(function() {
      $("div[name=1A]").toggle(this.value === "1" && 'input[name=SecondSelector]'.value === "A" )
    }).filter(":checked").change()

})
</script>

<html>
<p>
First choice
</p>
<input type="radio" name="FirstSelector" value="1">Option 1
<input type="radio" name="FirstSelector" value="2">Option 2


<p>
Second choice
</p>
<input type="radio" name="SecondSelector" value="A">Option A
<input type="radio" name="SecondSelector" value="B">Option B

<div name="1" class="hide">
This is the result of just Option 1
</div>

<div name="2" class="hide">
This is the result of just Option 2
</div>

<div name="1A" class="hide">
This is the result of 1 and A
</div>

<div name="1B" class="hide">
This is the result of 1 and B
</div>

<div name="2A" class="hide">
This is the result of 2 and A
</div>

<div name="2B" class="hide">
This is the result of 2 and B
</div>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/antonio1475/df7ra8eu/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the code. The first step to simplifying things is to use the same logic for every change:

```js
$('input').change(() => {
  const first = $('input[name=FirstSelector]:checked').val();
  const second = $('input[name=SecondSelector]:checked').val();
  $("div[name=1]").toggle(first === "1");
  $("div[name=2]").toggle(first === "2");
  $("div[name=1A]").toggle(first === "1" && second === "A");
  $("div[name=1B]").toggle(first === "1" && second === "B");
  $("div[name=2A]").toggle(first === "2" && second === "A");
  $("div[name=2B]").toggle(first === "2" && second === "B");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
First choice
</p>
<input type="radio" name="FirstSelector" value="1">Option 1
<input type="radio" name="FirstSelector" value="2">Option 2


<p>
Second choice
</p>
<input type="radio" name="SecondSelector" value="A">Option A
<input type="radio" name="SecondSelector" value="B">Option B

<div name="1" class="hide">
This is the result of just Option 1
</div>

<div name="2" class="hide">
This is the result of just Option 2
</div>

<div name="1A" class="hide">
This is the result of 1 and A
</div>

<div name="1B" class="hide">
This is the result of 1 and B
</div>

<div name="2A" class="hide">
This is the result of 2 and A
</div>

<div name="2B" class="hide">
This is the result of 2 and B
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In all modesty, here is the simplest solution:

```js
$(function() {

  var Msg = {};

  Msg['1-'] = 'This is the result of just Option 1'
  Msg['2-'] = 'This is the result of just Option 2'
  Msg['-A'] = 'This is the result of just Option A'
  Msg['-B'] = 'This is the result of just Option B'
  Msg['1A'] = 'This is the result of Options 1 and A'
  Msg['1B'] = 'This is the result of Options 1 and B'
  Msg['2A'] = 'This is the result of Options 2 and A'
  Msg['2B'] = 'This is the result of Options 2 and B'
  
  $('input[name=FirstSelector]').change( CalcMsg );
  $('input[name=SecondSelector]').change( CalcMsg );

  function CalcMsg() {
    var Ref = $('input[name=FirstSelector]:checked').val() || '-';
      Ref += $('input[name=SecondSelector]:checked').val()  || '-';

    $('#Msg').text( Msg[Ref] ).removeClass( "hide" );
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>  First choice </p>
<label><input type="radio" name="FirstSelector" value="1">Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="FirstSelector" value="2">Option 2</label>

<p> Second choice </p>
<label><input type="radio" name="SecondSelector" value="A">Option A</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="SecondSelector" value="B">Option B</label>

<div id="Msg" class="hide">
  This is the result of ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. This works! However, my code was a simple example - I don't have just text, but divs with quite a lot of HTML within, so your approach wouldn't be suitable for that.
But for displaying messages, it does work great! Thank you for looking at it!

Comment: Nothing forbids to use this same system to activate or deactivate the display of your different DIV, the value Ref (of the function CalcMsg) can become the suffix of the ID of your DIV, or else to use the contents of the Msg table (a JS object actually) to indicate the DIV's to target. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of issues with your code but to address that simple problem of the DIV not showing look into this issue, [get value from radio group using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723505/get-value-from-radio-group-using-jquery)

This line...

```
  $("div[name=1A]").toggle(this.value === "1" && $('input[name=SecondSelector]').val() === "A" )
```

You were missing the jQuery selector `$('')` around the `input[name=SecondSelector]`. Also you were trying to get the `value` when you should have been calling the `val()` function since it's a radio group.

Here's final

```
$('input[name=FirstSelector]').change(function() {
    console.log($('input[name=SecondSelector]').val());
    $("div[name=1A]").toggle(this.value === "1" && $('input[name=SecondSelector]').val() === "A" )
}).filter(":checked").change()
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. @ic3b3rg answer works. Thank you anyway!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a change I have made to the java-script code.

```
$('input[name=FirstSelector]').change(function() {
    var radioValue = $("input[name='SecondSelector']:checked").val();
    $("div[name=1A]").toggle(this.value === "1" && radioValue && radioValue === "A" )
}).filter(":checked").change()
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/145tbqx0/

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. @ic3b3rg answer works. Thank you anyway!! :)
PS: The fiddle is not updated