# creating a jquery timer: timer won't continue counting after manual edit

Tags: jquery, timer

I'm trying to build a simple timer application with the ability to override the timer manually. The timer is shown in hrs, mins and sec (each in their own input) field.

Everything seems to be working, but when you manually edit an input field, the timer stops updating. I've tried to re execute the timer function on `change`, but doesn't work.

Please see the following jsFiddle for a full example: http://jsfiddle.net/stiankarlsen/jXbr3/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is not very obvious but the issue is with the use of `timeSec.attr("value", timeSecNum + 1)` instead of using `timeSec.val(timeSecNum + 1)`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-obj-val-vs-obj-attrvalue) for a good explanation (assigning attributes vs. properties)

Comment: If this was satisfactory, could you mark this as the answer? thanks