# Undefined result in MYSQL Table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to add information to a MYSQL table using ajax.  If I go direct to the insert page it works fine, but as soon as I pass the variables through the ajax code, the results entered in to the database table all say undefined instead of giving their actual value.

HTML CODE

```
  <form action="social.php" method="POST" class="submit">
    <div id="facebook">
    <div class="row">
      <input name="facebook" type="text" id="facebook" placeholder="Add Your Facebook Link" size="50" value="<?php echo "$facebook"; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="twitter"><input name="twitter" id="twitter" type="text" placeholder="Add Your Twitter Link" size="50"  value="<?php echo "$twitter"; ?>"></div>
    <div id="googleplus"><input name="googleplus" id="googleplus" type="text" placeholder="Add Your Google + Link" size="50" value="<?php echo "$googleplus"; ?>"></div>
    <div id="linkedin"><input name="linkedin" type="text" id="linkedin" placeholder="Add Your Linkedin Link" size="50" value="<?php echo "$linkedin"; ?>"></div>
    <div id="socialsubmitbutton">
    <input type="hidden" name="usern" id="usern" value="<?php echo "$usern"; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
    </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript / Ajax

```
   <script type"text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('form.submit').submit(function () {
   var usern = $(this).find('.usern').attr('value');
   var facebook = $(this).find('.facebook').attr('value');
   var googleplus = $(this).find('.googleplus').attr('value');
var linkedin = $(this).find('.linkedin').attr('value');
var twitter = $(this).find('.twitter').attr('value');
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "social.php",
        data: "usern="+ usern +"& facebook="+ facebook +"& googleplus="+ googleplus +"& linkedin="+ linkedin +"& twitter="+ twitter,
        success: function(){
            $('form.submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeOut();});

        }
    });
return false;
});
  });
</script>
```

PHP

```
     include 'db.php';
$usern        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['usern']));
$facebook        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['facebook']));
$twitter        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['twitter']));
$linkedin       = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['linkedin']));
$googleplus        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['googleplus']));


$addClient  = "INSERT INTO settings (username, facebook, googleplus, linkedin, twitter) VALUES ('$usern', '$facebook', '$googleplus', '$linkedin', '$twitter')";
mysql_query($addClient) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tis piece of code:

```
...
var usern = $(this).find('.usern').attr('value');
var facebook = $(this).find('.facebook').attr('value');
var googleplus = $(this).find('.googleplus').attr('value');
var linkedin = $(this).find('.linkedin').attr('value');
var twitter = $(this).find('.twitter').attr('value');
...
```

you are selecting entities that have **class** "usern", "facebook", etc. You actually want to select entities by name, so the selectors should be like this:

```
...
var usern = $(this).find("[name='usern']").attr('value');
var facebook = $(this).find("[name='facebook']").attr('value');
...
```

Also, if you want to retrieve the current value of the inputs, you should use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-obj-val-vs-obj-attrvalue)

```
...
var usern = $(this).find("[name='usern']").val();
var facebook = $(this).find("[name='facebook']").val();
...
```

**EDIT:**

I would suggest, too, that instead of constructing your call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "social.php",
    data: "usern="+ usern +"& facebook="+ facebook +"& googleplus="+ googleplus +"& linkedin="+ linkedin +"& twitter="+ twitter,
    success: function(){
        $('form.submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeOut();});

    }
});
```

You do it like this, as this is way more readable and less error-prone:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "social.php",
    data: {
        usern : usern,
        facebook : facebook,
        googleplus : googleplus,
        linkedin : linkedin,
        twitter : twitter
    },
    success: function(){
        $('form.submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeOut();});

    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure you have `"` quotes within `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces between parameters;

Change

```
data: "usern="+ usern +"& facebook="+ facebook +"& googleplus="+ googleplus +"& linkedin="+ linkedin +"& twitter="+ twitter,
                         ^--remove                ^--remove                    ^--remove                ^--remove
```

to

```
data: "usern="+ usern +"&facebook="+ facebook +"&googleplus="+ googleplus +"&linkedin="+ linkedin +"&twitter="+ twitter,
```

**EDIT**

and also you need to find element by its name attribute

```
var usern = $(this).find("[name=usern]").val();
var facebook = $(this).find("[name=facebook]").val();
var googleplus = $(this).find("[name=googleplus]").val();
var linkedin = $(this).find("[name=linkedin]").val();
var twitter = $(this).find("[name=twitter]").val();
```

Comment: did u tried using `var usern = $('#usern').val();
var facebook = $('#facebook').val();
var googleplus = $('#googleplus').val();
var linkedin = $('#linkedin').val();
var twitter = $('#twitter').val();`

Comment: Ok i tried the edit, if i use the first one, it still says undefined, if i use the second one, then nothing is entered in to the tables

Comment: Ah, finally i got the problem. You have used multiple IDs. which is invalid. So you might need to find element by its name itself. Anyhow, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the right syntax to pass your data :

```
data: "usern="+ usern +"& facebook="+ facebook +"& googleplus="+ googleplus +"& linkedin="+ linkedin +"& twitter="+ twitter,
```

become

```
data: {'usern': usern,'facebook': facebook,'googleplus': googleplus, 'linkedin': linkedin, 'twitter': twitter},
```