# What is wrong with my JavaScript code? (Search bar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code here in JS and I can't figure out why it isn't doing what I want it to do. Basically, I have a search bar that should write "Search..." it in. When the user clicks on it, the text goes away and the bar goes blank. If the user clicks away without filling any text in, the "Search..." text returns.

Otherwise, the text the user enters stays in the bar. Up until this point my code works fine. The issue is this; when the user inputs something AND THEN takes it away, the bar remains blank, whereas the "Search..." text should return. (Notice: This does not occur if the user simply clicks on the bar and then clicks away; the default text returns as it should. It only happens if the users enters something and then takes it away.)

I can not figure out why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var search_default = 'Search...';
    $('input[type="search"]').attr('value', search_default).focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == search_default) {
            $(this).attr('value', '');
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).attr('value', search_default);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Give your html code also.

Comment: Why don't you use the placeholder attribute to set the Search... text?

Comment: Simply put, my HTML is: <p><input type="search"/></p> .

Comment: Your code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/6QEvq/

Comment: @kiks73 I'm a little new at JS, am I not accomplishing that with the line "$(this).attr('value', search_default);" ?

Comment: @user3426380 the `placeholder=""` attribute is html 5 , no js required. http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Comment: @Blowsie Oddly enough, it doesn't work that way on my browser (Chrome). :S

Comment: :) why don't use HTML <input type="text" placeholder="search ..." />

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val(value)` instead of `attr('value',value)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var search_default = 'Search...';
    $('input[type="search"]').val(search_default).focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == search_default) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val(search_default);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works! I'm new at JS (just started today). Can you explain why .val(value) works as opposed to attr('value', value)?

Comment: glad to help you :). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue) for explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the HTML, this is how i would do it:

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO - EDITED HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/p9HKw/)**

If you cannot edit the HTML, you would need to create the `data-default` attribute

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO 2 - NON EDITED HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/p9HKw/1/)**

Add a `data-default` tag to the element

```
<input type="search" data-default="Search..." value="Search...">
```

And the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    // when you focus on the search input
    $('input[type=search]').on('focus',function(e){

        // if the value is the same as the default value
        if( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-default') )
        {
            // make the value blank
            $(this).val('');
        }

    // when you move out of the search input
    }).on('blur',function(e){

        // if there is no value (blank)
        if( !$(this).val() )
        {
            // add back the default value
            $(this).val( $(this).attr('data-default') );
        }
    });
});
```