# Update display color from input[type=color]

Tags: jquery, html, input, colors

**Hi,**

I want to change the `value` attribute of a `<input type="color">` element. It works if I clicked it, but the display color of the input button is not changing. If I change the color manually from beginning, it works (but I have to change it on runtime).

Watch this JSFiddle to get what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/5u544/

Thanks and greetings
Mat

**Edit:** Like in the comments below, the problem was the [difference between object attributes and properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue). Credits to @Navin for this ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use the `.val()` property to set the value like this

```
$("#test").val("#ff66ff");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NavinKrishnan/5u544/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it works :) Is there a reason why attr("value",...) isn't working? I've tried .trigger("change") eg. as well.

Comment: @schlenger have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue

Comment: Great! Thanks for the fast answer.