# Why .attr('value') of hidden input element not returning original value from html string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically when invoking `.attr("value")` over a text box, It will return its value which was set in the markup, not the value which was set by using `.val()`.

For instance,

```
<input id="test" type="text" value="testing" />
```

Js:

```
$("#test").val("hello");
console.log($("#test").val()); //hello
console.log($("#test").attr('value')); //testing
```

But while doing the same over a hidden element, the result was different like below,

HTML:

```
<input id="test1" type="hidden" value="testing" />
```

Js:

```
$("#test1").val("hello");
console.log($("#test1").val()); //hello
console.log($("#test1").attr('value')); //hello
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S9mUL/1704/)

The value attribute got ignored if we set value for that element by using `.val()`. Anyone have idea on why is this happening? Relevant link which contains details for this behavior would be more helpful.

Comment: You can see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Interestingly, [`document.getElementById('test').defaultValue`](http://jsfiddle.net/S9mUL/1706/) also logs (in the demo) `"newVal"` (the jQuery-set string). @George: in versions [1.11.0](http://jsfiddle.net/S9mUL/1706/), [2.1.3](http://jsfiddle.net/S9mUL/1707/), and [3.0.0-alpha1](http://jsfiddle.net/S9mUL/1708/).

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I just tested with recent versions. You can see the exact version in my demo.

Comment: `.attr(...)` is only getting the objects value at the time of html creation. clearly it seems doing something unexpected in case of the hidden value.

Comment: An interesting finding! :( Is this a bug? The link provided does not seem to address the issue. jQuery version does not seem to matter. **The question is, why should it matter whether the element is of `type="hidden"` or not?. jQuery's `.val( newVal )` should NEVER change the attribute value!**

Comment: I agree @PeterKA, but you should be using `prop` for this operation, not `attr`.

Comment: This isn't specific to jQuery. Here's the same demo using raw Javascript, with the same results: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/S9mUL/1709/

Comment: so the answer should be in the spec, in regards to hidden type inputs, eh?

Comment: My apologies. I "misspoke". The jQuery version does seem to matter. Issue seems to exist in jQuery versions older than `1.8.x`. What changed in `1.9.x`? **Consider this question: If you change the elements value attribute, would the value property change?**

Comment: @PeterKA, the 'issue' is present with 2.1.3 as well.. the answer lyes with w3's markup spec on input type hidden - "The user does not interact with this field; instead, the VALUE attribute specifies the value of the field."..  http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html

Comment: @PeterKA, change the value of a input type submit, and should do the same thing.

Comment: @BrettCaswell, thanks for the explanation.  There seems to be more to it. Version of jQuery upto `1.8.3` do not seem to have this issue. The rest do. Why?

Comment: The already asked question doesn't seem to have official documentation in its answer. The link provided by brett can be considered.

Comment: @PeterKA Skipped updating the `defaultValue` property of hidden element while modifying the `value` property. This might have been a bug in older versions of jquery. They might have fixed it by updating the both while it comes to a hidden element, in recent versions.

Comment: @PeterKA, I'm not entirely familiar with the code base on this, but perhaps the reason is in line 122 of this changeset: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1017/files#r2031507

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hidden` inputs aren't ***user editable***, so you may find that the ***default and current values*** are the same for them. So the `.val()` and `.attr('value')` are the same for `hidden`element

As far as I get , the `value` attribute describes the ***default value*** for the element, not ***the current value***. Current Value is what you can access through the value property (which is what the jQuery `val()` does).

Comment: This can be considered semantically, but syntactically `.attr()` will return the value whatever set in markup as per the documentation.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy That is correct but when you use `.val()` with hidden field, it changes the value of the attribute `value` and so `.val()` and `.attr()` produce the same output

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Yes, and on hidden inputs changing the `.value` does alter the `value` attribute in the DOM.

Comment: yep, same is true for input type submit as well it seems: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.1.2.7

Comment: @BrettCaswell This is an interesting link. Yeah the answer resides there it seems.

Comment: @Bergi By mistake, I pressed that reopen link in my question, it reopened the post without any confirmation. My apologies. Can you redo what you have done previously?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: No, seems I can only cast one vote. But you should be able to close it yourself.