# how to get value of input type from dynamic table using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic-tables

I am working on ecommerce website.

My table gets value from session.
It looks like :
[image]

On **Checkout** I want to get all the values of table.

I have used **jquery** for this.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$('#chhk').on('click',function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert('click');
                var table = $("#tbl tbody");

                 table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
                    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                        product = $tds.eq(2).text(),
                        price = $tds.eq(3).text(),
                        quantity = $tds.eq(4).attr('value'),
                        total = $tds.eq(5).text();

                     alert('Row ' + (i + 1) + ':\nProduct: ' + product
                          + '\nPrice: ' + price
                           + '\nQuantity: ' + quantity
                          + '\nTotal: ' + total);
                });

            });
</script>
```

Here 
**'#chhk'** is checkout button id

**'#tbl'** is my table id

I am getting blank value of **quantity** by this script as it is **input field**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Try replace this:

```
                    quantity = $tds.eq(4).attr('value');
```

with:

```
                    quantity = $tds.eq(4).val();
```

As .attr('value') gives the value at the start, while .val() gives current property.

More info:
[jQuery .val() vs .attr("value")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue)

Comment: I have tried this before but getting  **quantity undefined.**

Comment: kindly check my below answer and let me know if I can use quantity script with **.eq**  syntax

Comment: Seems like value is in the input tag, and not in the td tag you get through your .eq syntax. That means that you have to get the input tag out of the td tag. `quantity = $tds.eq(4).children("input").val();` might work.

Comment: As I have mentioned earlier , it is dynamic table , so it is necessary that input type should be in td

Comment: Try `quantity = $tds.eq(4).children("input").val();` if you want to keep your .eq syntax.

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
 quantity = $tds.eq(4).attr('value'),
```

with

```
quantity = $tds.eq(4).find("input").val(),
```

Answer (score 0):

well I tried to do it separately and am getting expected result.

```
$('#chhk').on('click',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('click');
            var table = $("#tbl tbody");

             table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
                var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                    product = $tds.eq(2).text(),
                    price = $tds.eq(3).text(),
                    total = $tds.eq(5).text();
                    var qty = $(this).find('td input:first').val();

                 alert('Row ' + (i + 1) + ':\nProduct: ' + product
                      + '\nPrice: ' + price
                      + '\nTotal: ' + total
                      +'\n Qua:' + qty);
            });

        });
```

Have dealed **quantity** separately.