# Why Google Chrome dev tools ->elements don't reflect some changes made by Javascript in DOM?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following form:

```
<form>
    <input type = "text" id = "test" class = 'test'>
</form>
```

And the following Javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#test').addClass('thereIsNoSpoon').val('blah');
    })
</script>
```

When I open the page, and look at Chrome's developer tools -> elements, I can see on the input element, that the class 'thereIsNoSpoon' **is** visible (Chrome noticed the change, and displays it for me), and in the same moment it does not reflect the change in 'value' attribute. That is, I can see this change on the page, but not in Dev Tools.

I have two questions - why is that and what are the rules behind reflecting/not reflecting changes made to DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery `$().val('some_value')` set the value property of the element.it wont alter the value attribute of the element.you can see value attribut when you use `$().attr('value','some_value')`

[check this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue)

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to read about those properties and attributes :) before I thought that this is only Jquery-related (that is, differentiation properties/attributes are jquery's concepts).

Comment: Btw if somebody's interested here is the difference between properties/attributes explained very well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html