# check if input email value is the same as other input email value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to check if input value of email is the same with other input value of email.You can add persons like a accordian. So every person has an email. But it is not possible that two or more put the same email address in the text box

I have this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // Form validation
   $(".klantregistratie form").validate({
     rules: {
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Bedrijfsnaam: "required",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Postcode: "required",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Plaats: "required",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres: {
         required: true,
         email: true
       },
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_KvK_nummer: "required",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_naam_eigenaar: "required",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_mobiel: "required"
     },
     messages: {
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Bedrijfsnaam: "De bedrijfsnaam is niet ingevuld",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Postcode: "De postcode is niet ingevuld",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Plaats: "De plaats is niet ingevuld",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres: {
         required: "Je hebt geen email adres ingevuld",
         email: "Je hebt geen geldig email adres ingevuld"
       },
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_KvK_nummer: "Het KVK nummer is niet ingevuld",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_naam_eigenaar: "De naam van de eigenaar is niet ingevuld",
       verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_mobiel: "Het (mobiele) telefoon nummer is niet ingevuld"
     }
   });

   // Hide the textarea
   $('#verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Contactpersonen').parent().parent().hide();

   $('input[name=FormCH1_h]').val(x);

   // Add extra contact clicked?
   $('#add-contact p a').click(function() {
     // Make a copy of the first input fields
     html = $('#new-contact').children().clone();

     // Get number of tabs in the accordion
     var index = $('#accordion h3').length;

     // Remove the values
     html.find("input[type=text]").val("");
     html.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);

     // New 'id', 'for' and 'name' attribute names
     html.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
       me = $(this);
       attr = me.attr('id');
       number = attr.split('_')[2];
       newNumber = parseInt(index) + 1;
       newAttr = attr.replace(number, newNumber);
       me.attr('id', newAttr).attr('name', newAttr).next().attr('for', newAttr);
     });

     // Insert it at the end
     $('#accordion').append(html);
     $('#accordion').accordion('refresh');

     // Set last tab to active
     $("#accordion").accordion({
       active: index
     });

     // Cancel the click
     return false;
   });

   // Submit clicked?
   $('.submit-button input').click(function() {
     // Set variables
     var html = '';
     var i = 1;

     // Loop through all the input fields for contacts
     $('#accordion .user-row').each(function(uindex, uvalue) {
       html += '<tr>';

       if (($('#contactpersonen-email').attr('value')) == $('#contactpersonen-email').attr('value')); {
         alert('the same');
       }

       $(this).find('input').each(function(index, value) {

         // Check if input type is a checkbox
         if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
           var JaNee = 'Nee';
           if ($(this).is(":checked")) JaNee = 'Ja';
           html = html + '<td>' + JaNee + '</td>';
         } else {
           // Add the value into the html
           html = html + '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';
         }
       });

       html += '</tr>';
     });

     // Set the value from the textarea to the generated html
     $('#verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Contactpersonen').val('<table>' + html + '</table>');
   });
 });

 $(function() {
   $("#accordion").accordion({
     heightStyle: "content"
   });
 });
```

So I try to compare like this:

```
if (($('#contactpersonen-email').attr('value')) == $('#contactpersonen-email').attr('value')); {
    alert('the same');
}
```

[image]

This also doesnt work:

```
  if(($('#contactpersonen-email').val()) ==  $('#contactpersonen-email').val() )
                {
                        alert('the same');
                    }
```

I have it now like this:

```
<![CDATA[
                            $(document).ready(function()
                            {
                                // Form validation
                                $(".klantregistratie form").validate({
                                    rules: {
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Bedrijfsnaam: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Postcode: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Plaats: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres: {
                                            required: true,
                                            email: true
                                        },
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_KvK_nummer: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_naam_eigenaar: "required",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_mobiel: "required"
                                    },
                                    messages: {
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Bedrijfsnaam: "De bedrijfsnaam is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Postcode: "De postcode is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Plaats: "De plaats is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Emailadres: {
                                            required: "Je hebt geen email adres ingevuld",
                                            email: "Je hebt geen geldig email adres ingevuld"
                                        },
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_KvK_nummer: "Het KVK nummer is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_naam_eigenaar: "De naam van de eigenaar is niet ingevuld",
                                        verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Telefoon_mobiel: "Het (mobiele) telefoon nummer is niet ingevuld"
                                    }
                                });

                                // Hide the textarea
                                $('#verploegen_form_klantregistratie_Contactpersonen').parent().parent().hide();

                                // Add extra contact clicked?
                                $('#add-contact p a').click(function()
                                {
                                    // Make a copy of the first input fields
                                    html = $('#new-contact').children().clone();

                        // Get number of tabs in the accordion
                        var index = $('#accordion h3').length;

                                    // Remove the values
                                    html.find("input[type=text]").val("");
                  html.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);

                        // New 'id', 'for' and 'name' attribute names
                        html.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                            me = $(this);
                            attr = me.attr('id');
                            number = attr.split('_')[2];
                            newNumber = parseInt(index) + 1;
                            newAttr = attr.replace(number, newNumber);
                            me.attr('id', newAttr).attr('name', newAttr).next().attr('for', newAttr);
                        });                  

                                    // Insert it at the end
                        $('#accordion').append(html);
                        $('#accordion').accordion('refresh');

                        // Set last tab to active
                        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: index });

                                    // Cancel the click
                                    return false;
                                });

                                // Submit clicked?
                                $('.submit-button input').click(function()
                                {
                                    // Set variables
                                    var html = '';
                                    var i = 1;

                        // Loop through all the input fields for contacts
                        $('#accordion .user-row').each(function (uindex, uvalue) {
           //Niels                      
                    var mails = $('.contactpersonen-email').map(function(){
                     return $(this).val();
    //console.log($(this).val());
                    }).get(); 

Array.prototype.areUnique = function() {
    var l = this.length;
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<l; j++) {
            if (this[i] === this[j]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

if (!mails.areUnique()) {
    alert('values are not unique');
} else {
    alert('values are unique');
}
```

//Niels

But every time it says Vlaues are unique

I have it liket this:

```
    // Loop through all the input fields for contacts
                            $('#accordion .user-row').each(function (uindex, uvalue) {
                            var mails = $('.contactpersonen-email').map(function(){                 
                            return $(this).val();   
                            }).get(); 
console.log(mails);
                            ["email 1"]
```

klant-worden:661 ["email 1"]

Comment: Oh gosh the indentation. How bad your tab key looks like ?

Comment: it is not my tab anyway. It is the file where I got this. THere is no syntax or what every in that program. So sorry for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue

Comment: There are so many tools that automatically correct the indentation. So please if you expect help then take the time to format your code that it is readable.

Comment: @brso05 - that's not going to have any effect since `$('#contactpersonen-email')` will always === `$('#contactpersonen-email')` would be better advice to just remove that whole block..

Comment: So how to compare the values in the foreach?

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible please check my answer. I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`.

`.attr('value')` will give you the value before editing, while `.val()` will give you the current value.

Comment: I did that: 
      if(($('#contactpersonen-email').val()) ==  $('#contactpersonen-email').val() )
       {
        alert('the same');
       }

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible - you should pay closer attention man. now you've got extra perenthesis. and you're still comparing exactly the same thing to itself.

Comment: ? So what you suggest then? Thank you. It is in a foreach

Answer (score 0):

semicolon at end of if statement:

```
        if(($('#contactpersonen-email').attr('value')) ==  $('#contactpersonen-email').attr('value') );
                            {
                                    alert('the same');
                            }
```

should be:

```
        if(($('#contactpersonen-email').attr('value')) ==  $('#contactpersonen-email').attr('value') )
                            {
                                    alert('the same');
                            }
```

It's a good argument for adding opening braces ont he same line as the conditional test, imho.

Comment: ok, I did that removing the semiccolon. But every time the alert message apears

Comment: of course it is :P you're checking to see if a value is equal to itself, which it will always be. maybe compare it with a differenet value instead :P

Comment: @Hector how does adding braces at the end help?  This is still valid, but doesn't give expected :  `if (false) ; { \n alert("true"); \n }`  (\n for newline as this is a comment)

Comment: So what can it be?? I realy dont understand why it not works.

Answer (score 0):

**[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/225ggz8m/)**

Problem is, `id` html attribute have to be unique. You should give a unique id to your fields inside the "contact" part of your form and use a class instead :

```
<input type="email" class="contactpersonen-email" id="contactpersonen-email0" />
```

Then, you retrieve all values of the `.contactpersonen-email` fields :

```
var mails = $('.contactpersonen-email').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get(); 
/* "values" now contains an array like ['mail1@website.tld', 'mail2@website.tld', 'mail2@website.tld'] */
```

Then you can use this simple function to check if all values are unique :

```
Array.prototype.areUnique = function() {
    var l = this.length;
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<l; j++) {
            if (this[i] === this[j]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

At last, just do this simple test :

```
if (!mails.areUnique()) {
    alert('values are not unique');
} else {
    alert('values are unique');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it

Comment: But how to implement this in jquery.validate plugin?

Comment: but is show only the first value of email. And if generate two contacts with to emails you will get : ["jj"]
klant-worden:655 ["jj"]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but the question was about how to check if two inputs have the same value, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, But I always get the same value. Even if I put two different values in the email text fiedls: Because I first check if the correct emails will be returned. Look at my edit post

Comment: ok. I get the correct emails back. But how to get the message by the email text box

Comment: But It returns three arrays: ["sdfsdf", "houi", ""]
klant-worden:661 ["sdfsdf", "houi", ""]
klant-worden:661 ["sdfsdf", "houi", ""]

Comment: oke, I get now one array back: ["kkk", "kppp", ""] . but why is there a third value ""?? I just have two email text boxes. And I get every time the message: they have the same values

Comment: also your exmaple: it says every time they are unique, with different values