# about jQuery html(), attr() and val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy some DOM nodes by html() method. I use val() to modify the input value, then use html() to copy the input node, but the value of the copied input is old!! When I use attr() to modify the input value, then copy it by html(), it looks like RIGHT!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="con1"><input type="text" value="1"></p>
<p id="con2"></p>

<button onclick="doTest1()">test1</button>
<button onclick="doTest2()">test2</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var doTest1 = function() {
  $("#con1 > input").val("2");
  $("#con2").html( $("#con1").html() );
};

var doTest2 = function() {
  $("#con1 > input").attr("value","2");
  $("#con2").html( $("#con1").html() );
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question rather than linking to an outside source.

Comment: Two upvotes right off the bat for a vague question with no code? I smell sock puppets.

Comment: are you basically just trying to clone an element?

Comment: Try .clone() instead of .html(). https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Try changing the value with `val()` after appending.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery implements `.html()`, `.attr()` and `.val()` like,

> **.html()** - `element.innerHTML();`
>
> **.attr(x, y)** - `element.setAttribute(x, y);`
>
> **.val(x)** - `element.value = x;`

When you run `.html()` after you set the value with `.val()`, you basically just copy the entire element's inner HTML with its not-updated `value` attribute like (in your sample),

```
<input type="text" value="1">
```

And that's why the value would still be `1`.

By changing the value with `.val()` after page load, does not update the attribute `value` in your `input`. Even for the element above, if you run,

```
$('input').val('2'); // <input type="text" value="1">
```

But if you run with `.attr()`,

```
$('input').attr('2'); // <input type="text" value="2">
```

*Note that `.html()` gets the exact HTML contents of the element.*

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but it seems like it should be deemed a jQuery bug.

Comment: Perfect answer! I fully understand it.

Comment: @PHPglue Nah, I don't think it should be a bug. Setting an `element.value` in js does not update the HTML contents in the document. While `element.setAttribute` does.

Comment: That is the same as saying that using the `.html(contentHere)` method should not change the `.html()`  method's output. It's just changing the `Element.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.clone()` instead. Here is an example:

```
<button type="button" id="btnClone">Clone Input</button>
    <div id="inputContainer">
        <input id="myInput" type="text"/>
    </div>


$('#btnClone').click(function (e) {
    $('#myInput').clone().attr('id', 'myInput2').appendTo('#inputContainer');
})
```

**NOTE** When cloning, be cautious of the element you're cloning. For example, if it's got an `id` attribute, that will be cloned too. This would result in 2 separate elements with the same `id`.

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it!

Comment: Don't think this answers why this is happening. I believe OP wants to know why both results don't look like `doTest2`.

Comment: Yes, but OP is also asking how to solve his actual problem which is making a clone of an element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var doTest1 = function() {
  $("#con1 > input").val("2");

  $("#con2").html($("#con1").html());
  console.log("con 1 val " + $("#con1 > input").val());
  console.log("con 1 attr " + $("#con1 > input").attr('value'));

  console.log("con 2 val " + $("#con2 > input").val());
  console.log("con 2 attr " + $("#con2 > input").attr('value'));
};

var doTest2 = function() {
  $("#con1 > input").attr("value", "2");
  $("#con2").html($("#con1").html());

  console.log("con 1 val " + $("#con1 > input").val());
  console.log("con 1 attr " + $("#con1 > input").attr('value'));

  console.log("con 2 val " + $("#con2 > input").val());
  console.log("con 2 attr " + $("#con2 > input").attr('value'));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="con1">
  <input type="text" value="1">
</p>
<p id="con2"></p>

<button onclick="doTest1()">test1</button>
<button onclick="doTest2()">test2</button>
```

When you look the at console you can see that even if the displayed value change using the method `.val()` in the html the attr value is still 1 in the first example. So when you copy the html using `.html()` what it copied is `value='1'`

While in example 2 when you change the value using `.attr()` the attr value changed to `2` that is why when you copied it using `.html()` you get the `value='2'`

I hope the demo made sense