# Value edited with jQuery is empty after submit

Tags: jquery

I have an input for which I set the value after an AJAX request, but when I submit the form the value of this input is empty

Here's my input :

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="NbEmprunteurs" id="NbEmprunteurs"/>
```

and here's how I set in the callback function :

```
$('#NbEmprunteurs').attr('value',data.nbEmprunteurs);
```

on submit i get all the other inputs but this one, any idea why ?

Comment: Can you show full code?

Comment: When using jQuery, why don't you just use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to set the value of the input field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .val() vs .attr("value")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.val()` to set the value.

```
$('#NbEmprunteurs').val(data.nbEmprunteurs);
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/val/

`.attr()` doesn't work because it changes the HTML element attribute but not the current state. Attributes are key-value pairs that you type in HTML tags `<input ... >` and state is an information about the DOM element stored inside JS engine. In some cases the HTML element state can differ from the attribute values. For example, input's value: when you type something in an input, its `value` attribute isn't changed (you can see it in a browser dev tool).