# JSP getting Input Value

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jakarta-ee

for some reason i get null values.
Im filling the value from label input with a defaultvalue form the database
That works fine

```
<label for="input_first_name">Vorname:</label> 
<input id="input_first_name" value=<%out.print(html_contents.get("vorname"));%> type="text" class="form-control">
```

Later in script:

```
data["vorname"] = document.querySelector('#input_first_name').value;
```

I thought about the scriptfunction takes the value of the label and not the label/input. And the label value is empty. 
If so. How can I change that?

Comment: Possibly related to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue).

Comment: (1) I do not know what is stored in `html_contents.get("vorname")`, but I bet it does not contain the quotes to be rendered correctly as HTML attribute. (2) It is much clearer to use `<%= ... %>` instead of `<% out.print(...); %>` in JSP. So can you please change the JSP code to: `<input id="input_first_name" value="<%= html_contents.get("vorname") %>" type="text" class="form-control">`