# Problem in function delete CodeIgniter with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to delete a register in a table instrumentos, I'm using codeignite with AJAX and I have this function in my controller

```
public function deleteInstrument(){
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    $sql = $this->db->where('id',$id)->delete('instrumentos');
    $r['response'] = 2;
    $r['content'] = 'deleted';
    echo json_encode($r);
}
```

And I have in my JavaScript the next function to delete:

```
function confirmarEliminar(){
    $("body").on("click","#tablaInstrumentos button",function(event){
        idseleccion=$(this).attr("value");
        alertify.confirm('Eliminar Registro',
                 'Esta seguro de eliminar el registro?',
                  function(idseleccion){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: base_url+'admin_ajax/deleteInstrument',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data:{id:idseleccion},
                        beforeSend:function(){
                        },
                        success:function(r){
                           if(r==2 ){
                               alert(id)

                           }
                        },
                        error:function(xhr, status, msg){
                            console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                   }

            , function(){ alertify.error(idseleccion)});

    });}
```

I have this error in the console output

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
at i (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at Function.w.param (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at Function.ajax (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (configuracion.js?1550431424:80)
at Object.callback (alertify.min.js:3)
```

Comment: without seeing your mark-up I can only guess: `idseleccion=$(this).attr("value");` should be `idseleccion=$(this).val();` see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312820/jquery-val-vs-attrvalue AND the variable base_url? is it defined? I can't see how?

Comment: I Solve my problem with your help, really thanks my friend, you are the best

Comment: I'm happy that my comment helped you. Anyway, to make your question useful for other people, please consider to update your question to be more on focus and also to provide an answer, how you managed to solve it, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code in js:
function confirmarEliminar(id) {

```
            $.post(base_url + "admin_ajax/deleteInstrument", {id: id}, function (data) {
                if (data.code == '1') {
                    bootbox.alert(data.message, function () {
                        $("#your row id" + id).remove();


                    });
                } else {
                    bootbox.alert('Something went wrong');
                }
                $(window).unblock();
            });
```

}

Controller Code:

public function deleteInstrument($id){
}