# ASP.net getting RadioButtonList value on content page with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I'm having a problem with my JavaScript code having moved it over to a content page in ASP.

It worked perfectly on a stand alone page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validateQ12(oSrc, args) {
            var rbtnList = document.getElementsByName('rbtn12');
            var noClicked = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < rbtnList.length; i++) {
                if (rbtnList[i].checked) {
                    noClicked = rbtnList[i].value == "No";
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (noClicked) {
                args.IsValid = true;                   
            }
            else
                args.IsValid = args.Value.trim().length > 0;                   
        }
    </script>
```

I have gone through the html on both pages, on the one that worked had

```
<input id="rbtn12_1" type="radio" name="rbtn12" value="No" checked="checked" onclick="Q12iNo();">
```

The new one inside a content page has

```
<input id="MainContent_rbtn12_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rbtn12" value="No" checked="checked" onclick="Q12iNo();">
```

Clearly the name change must be causing the problem. How do I reference this new name in my javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the rendered element name use the following:

```
<%= rbtn12.UniqueID %>
```

However in your case this may still not work as it looks like you need to loop through each radio button item.

See the following post:

[Find out if radio button is checked with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272507/find-out-if-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery)

Which shows how to determine if a radio button collection has a selected value.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you were trying to do, glad it helped!

Comment: All it does is find out which one is checked so I can use that information to call my ASP Validation controls. After adding what you said it works exactly how it did on the stand alone page before I had to put it into a content page, so thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you possibly add a className to your control and use getElementByClassName?

```
<input id="MainContent_rbtn12_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rbtn12" value="No" checked="checked" onclick="Q12iNo();" CssClass="Radio">

<script type="text/javascript">
        function validateQ12(oSrc, args) {
            var rbtnList = document.getElementsByClassName('Radio');
            var noClicked = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < rbtnList.length; i++) {
                if (rbtnList[i].checked) {
                    noClicked = rbtnList[i].value == "No";
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (noClicked) {
                args.IsValid = true;                   
            }
            else
                args.IsValid = args.Value.trim().length > 0;                   
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: No ASP doesn't give me the option for class name, just CSSClass which they all have the same one.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant Cssclass. Please see edit. And you want them to be the same don't you?

Comment: I have 30+ radio buttons in my code, that was just one of them, they all have the same cssclass, but thanks that may work for someone else.