# How to check if radio button is checked in jquery(javascript)

Tags: jquery

Ok,
so I'm using wordpress contact form 7 and I added some radiobuttons there. The code looks like this

```
[radio radio-681 id:radio1 "1" "2" "3"]
```

When I'm using dropdowns in that form they look like this

```
[select* three id:three include_blank class:contactForm "2" "3" "4"]
```

And I can call that in jquery like this

```
$('#three').change(function() {
    if ($("#three").val() == "3") {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Now my question is, how can I check if a radiobutton is checked?

EDIT: Thank you all for your fast response it works now.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272507/find-out-if-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery

Comment: How is this related to Wordpress?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if($('#three').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($('#radio_button').is(':checked'))
{
 // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if($("#three").attr('checked') === 'checked' )
{
    //Do something
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourRadioButton').is(':checked')
```

or

```
$('.setOfRadioButtons:checked').val()
```