# How to check which radio button is checked in cakephp using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp-2.3

I have code

```
$options = array('hours' => 'Hours', 'km' => 'Km', 'unit' =>"Unit");
                            $attributes = array('legend' => false);
echo $this->Form->radio('unit_type', $options, $attributes);
```

Now I would like to check which radio button is checked in javascript. I used

```
$("input[name='data[Equipment][unit_type]']:checked").val();
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Pleas check out this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272507/find-out-if-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: @irfan  I also tried the above link but its not working.

Comment: @Bina can u create a fiddle url?

Comment: It worked when I used this $("input:radio[id=myID]").click(function())

Answer (score 0):

Try This

$("input[name='data[Equipment][unit_type]']").is(":checked");

Comment: An explanation and/or working example would be helpful.