# check if radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checked

I have two radio buttons:

```
<input checked="checked" class="survey_kind_input" type="radio" value="Short">
<input class="survey_kind_input" type="radio" value="Thorough">
```

I have the following javascript:

```
if($('.survey_kind_input').checked){
    alert('in survey kind checked');
}
```

But it is not working.  How do I successfully make the alert work?

Comment: do you want the alert to happen when its clicked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out if radio button is checked with JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272507/find-out-if-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking properly whether it is checked or not, so it won't work. Instead, use `is()` and `:checked` to check whether it is checked:

```js
if($('.survey_kind_input').is(':checked')){
    alert('in survey kind checked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input checked="checked" class="survey_kind_input" type="radio" value="Short">
<input class="survey_kind_input" type="radio" value="Thorough">
```

Comment: Great, thanks, will accept in 5 minutes when SO allows me

Answer (score 1):

Either use `get()` to retrieve the javascript Dom element and use `checked` or use `is(:checked)`

```
 if($('.survey_kind_input').get()[0].checked){
        alert('in survey kind checked');
    }
```

or

```
if($('.survey_kind_input').is(':checked'){
    alert('in survey kind checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($('.survey_kind_input').is(":checked"){
   alert('in survey kind checked');
}
```