# How to check if any options of radio buttons are clicked in JavaScript or with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use into an if statement if any of the options are selected...like:

> ```
> <script>
>     if(any_selected){
>       if(option){
>         //do somthing
>       }
>     }
>     else{
>       //do somthing else
>     } </script
> ```

This is the html code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="event-c" id="event-c" class="col-sm-4 control-label"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">button</button></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7"> 
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <form>
        <c:forEach items="${getNamesForLegend}" var="members">
            <div class="radio">
                <div class="panel-body" id="radio-c"><label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value=""><c:out value="${members.name}"/> <c:out value="${members.lastname}"/> 
        <input type="hidden" name="a"<c:out value="${members.mySubordinate}"/>></div></label>
             </div>
        </c:forEach>

    </form>

</div>
</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out if radio button is checked with JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272507/find-out-if-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: Check the `length` of the jQuery selection ...

Comment: `if ($('input[name="optradio"]:selected').length) { /* do something */ });`

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
if($('input:[name=optradio]:checked').length)
{
//selected
}
else
{
//not selected
}
```

If you want to check particular group of radio button use above.Or else try `$('input:checkbox:checked').length`

Answer (score 0):

Calculate `:checked` count.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input').change(function () {
    if ($('input:checked').length) {
      $('span').css({'background-color': 'green'});
    } else {
      $('span').css({'background-color': 'red'});
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value=""/>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value=""/>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value=""/>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value=""/>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value=""/>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value=""/>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value=""/>
<input type="radio" name="optradio" value=""/>
<hr/>
<span></span>
```

---

Keep in mind that your `#radio-c` is in loop and will have non-unique ID per page.