# Check specific radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to return true/false in one my my jquery methods depending on the check of a 2 radio buttons and if it's selected or not

I've tried several things but have not been able to get this right, it still submit the form without giving error that the buttons are not selected.

HTML Code

```
<label class="checkout-item" for="payment_1">Cash On Delivery</label>
<input type="radio" name="payment" class="radio" id="payment_1" value="3" iscod="1" onclick="selectPayment(this)">

<label class="checkout-item" for="payment_2">Credit Card / Debit Card</label>
<input type="radio" name="payment" class="radio" id="payment_2" value="9" checked="" iscod="0" onclick="selectPayment(this)">

<label class="checkout-item" for="ECS_NEEDINSURE_1">Home Delivery</label>
<input name="shipping" type="radio" id="ECS_NEEDINSURE_1" value="3" checked="true" supportcod="1" insure="0" class="radio" onclick="selectShipping(this)">

<label class="checkout-item" for="ECS_NEEDINSURE_2">Self-pickup</label>
<input name="shipping" type="radio" id="ECS_NEEDINSURE_2" value="8" supportcod="1" insure="0" class="radio" onclick="selectShipping(this)">
```

Javascript

```
function checkOrderForm(frm) {
    var paymentSelected = false;
    var shippingSelected = false;

    // Check whether the payment method is selected
    for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
        if (frm.elements[i].name == 'shipping' && frm.elements[i].checked) {
            shippingSelected = true;
        }

        if (frm.elements[i].name == 'payment' && frm.elements[i].checked) {
            paymentSelected = true;
        }
    }

    if (!shippingSelected) {
        alert(flow_no_shipping);
        return false;
    }

    if (!paymentSelected) {
        alert(flow_no_payment);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: why aren't you using the checked attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2272532/2134604

Comment: Please elaborate if you think i am making any mistake

Comment: Yes function is being called when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you would only like this test to pass if BOTH of the radio buttons are checked. Currently, as long as one radio button in each group is checked, the code variable will be set to true, ignoring the state of the other radio button.

For example, if ONLY one of your `shipping` radio buttons was checked, the `shippingSelected` variable would be set to true and it would remain true.

A way to fix this is to begin with `shippingSelected` and `paymentSelected` set to true, and if one of the radio buttons are found to be unchecked, the variable will be set to false.

Here's an example:

```
var paymentSelected = true;
var shippingSelected = true;

// Check whether the payment method is selected
for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {
    if (frm.elements[i].name == 'shipping' && !frm.elements[i].checked) {
        shippingSelected = false;
    }

    if (frm.elements[i].name == 'payment' && !frm.elements[i].checked) {
        paymentSelected = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#payment_1").checked` to check whether the radio is checked or not. Similarly you could use other ID's to check whether they are selected or not.

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bf8bo43t/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" name="frm_payment_types">
    <label class="checkout-item" for="payment_1">Cash On Delivery</label>
    <input type="radio" name="payment" class="radio" id="payment_1" value="3" iscod="1" onclick="selectPayment(this)">

    <label class="checkout-item" for="payment_2">Credit Card / Debit Card</label>
    <input type="radio" name="payment" class="radio" id="payment_2" value="9" iscod="0" onclick="selectPayment(this)">

    <label class="checkout-item" for="ECS_NEEDINSURE_1">Home Delivery</label>
    <input name="shipping" type="radio" id="ECS_NEEDINSURE_1" value="3" supportcod="1" insure="0" class="radio" onclick="selectShipping(this)">

    <label class="checkout-item" for="ECS_NEEDINSURE_2">Self-pickup</label>
    <input name="shipping" type="radio" id="ECS_NEEDINSURE_2" value="8" supportcod="1" insure="0" class="radio" onclick="selectShipping(this)">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return checkOrderForm();" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(){
        var payment_1 = document.getElementById('payment_1');
        var payment_2 = document.getElementById('payment_2');

        var ECS_NEEDINSURE_1 = document.getElementById('ECS_NEEDINSURE_1');
        var ECS_NEEDINSURE_2 = document.getElementById('ECS_NEEDINSURE_2');

        if((payment_1.checked == true || payment_2.checked == true) && (ECS_NEEDINSURE_1.checked == true || ECS_NEEDINSURE_2.checked == true)){
            return true;
        }
        else if(payment_1.checked == false && payment_2.checked == false){
            alert("Please select Cash On Delivery or Credit Card / Debit Card.");
        }
        else if(ECS_NEEDINSURE_1.checked == false && ECS_NEEDINSURE_2.checked == false){
            alert("Please select Home Delivery or Self-pickup.");
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```