# Check if bootstrap radio button is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a set of radio buttons using bootstrap and now I need to do a check to determine which button is active (To determine what string to use later in my project).

Currently I'm just trying to get an alert to appear for debugging:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var rg_eu = document.getElementById('option1');

    $('#searchplayer1').keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(keycode == '13') { 
            if($(document.getElementById('option1')).hasClass('active')) {
                alert(rg_eu);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

However my alert doesn't appear. Also tried checking with 'focus' and 'btn btn-secondary active' - but nothing seemed to work. Do I have to do this in some unconventional manner because it's done through bootstrap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out if radio button is checked with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272507/find-out-if-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: Yes, bootstrap applies the `active` class to the label, not the button itself.

Comment: in jQuery... if ( $('#option1') **.is(':checked')** )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap applies the `active` class to the label, not the button itself.

Here is one way to check the button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchplayer1').keypress(function(e) {
        var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(keycode == '13') { 
            if($('#option1').is(':checked')) {
                alert('option checked');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a selector in jquery which gives you the checked radio button in a particular radio group:

> if(jQuery("input[name="option1"]:checked"))
>   {
>   alert('radio is active');
>   }

other methods ,

```
1. $('#option1').is(':checked') 
2. $('#option1').prop('checked')
```

Refer the following link
https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/