# How to check which radio button is checked with jquery?

Tags: jquery, function

I'm trying to print text depending on which radio button is checked.
Can you tell me what's wrong?

Just getting the "error" output.

```
<input type="radio" name="feedback-form-visit-again" id="genderm" class="gendercheck" value="0" required> m
<input type="radio" name="feedback-form-visit-again" id="genderw" class="gendercheck" value="1"> w

<span class="gendertest">*Output*</span>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gendercheck").change(function() {
    if (gender.value == 0) {
      $(".gendertest").text("m");
    } else if (gender.value == 1) {
      $(".gendertest").text("w");
    } else {
      $(".gendertest").text("error");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: what is `gender`? you don't appear to declare it or assign it anywhere.

Comment: What is `gender` - you never defined it. If you replace `gender` with `this` - it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out if radio button is checked with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272507/find-out-if-radio-button-is-checked-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define `gender` in your code (since your trying to access the `value` property of `gender` via `gender.value`).

Try something like this (I tested and it works, by the way):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gendercheck').change(function() {
    var selectedRadio = $('.gendercheck:checked'); // this is the "checked" radio button that has the class you're using. using .value would be more of the vanilla JS way, which isn't bad, but if you wanted to do it the jQuery way, just get the val like this --> selectedRadio.val(); 
    if (selectedRadio.val() == 0) {
      $('.gendertest').text('m');
    } else if (selectedRadio.val() == 1) {
      $('.gendertest').text('w');
    } else {
      $('.gendertest').text('error');
    }
  });
});
```

For fun, just wanted to show you an example with fewer lines of code. Basically, print the radio input's value instead of defining the if/else statements. 
You'd need to modify your html inputs:

```
<input type="radio" name="feedback-form-visit-again" id="genderm" class="gendercheck" value="m" required> men
<input type="radio" name="feedback-form-visit-again" id="genderw" class="gendercheck" value="w"> women
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gendercheck').change(function() {
    var selectedRadio = $('.gendercheck:checked'); // the checked radio
    $('.gendertest').text( selectedRadio.val() ); // output with the radio input's val
  });
});
```

Comment: `this` in the change handler for radio buttons will be the one that was selected.  no reason to look it up.

Comment: @Taplar - true, but given the question related to jQuery, I was just showing the "jQuery way".

Comment: Doing it the "jQuery way" doesn't mean introducing unnecessary lookups

Comment: Calling it "unnecessary" seems more pedantic than anything. Lots of folks start out learning JS via jQuery. Since the OP is specifically looking at how to do it via jQuery, showing it this way offers more detail on jQuery's methods.

Comment: It's teaching people an inefficent way to use the library, which just encourages people to use it incorrectly and promote the idea amongst some people that the library isn't efficient.  And yes, given that you already have a reference to the element with `this` or the `e.target` off the event that you can pass in, it is highly unnecessary.

Comment: It's not "inefficient" nor "highly unnecessary". That's hyperbole. It's a jQuery question, which to me suggest the OP may be just starting out. The difference in DOM time/computation for my code vs `$(this).val()` is going to be imperceptible on the frontend, and my answer gives the OP more awareness of jQuery's utilities.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".gendercheck").on("change", function() {
  var selected_ID = ($(this).attr('id'));
  if (selected_ID == "genderm") {
    $(".gendertest").text("m");
  } else if (selected_ID == "genderw") {
    $(".gendertest").text("w");
  } else {
    $(".gendertest").text("error");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="feedback-form-visit-again" id="genderm" class="gendercheck" value="0" required> m
<input type="radio" name="feedback-form-visit-again" id="genderw" class="gendercheck" value="1"> w
<br>
<span class="gendertest">*Output*</span>
```