# How to detect if a certain radio button is checked with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, radio-button

I'm using the jQuery Validate plug-in and need to require a field if a certain radio button is checked. How can I determine if a certain country is selected?

For example, if the Canada radio button is checked, then require this field. This isn't right, but it's something along these lines:

```
depends: function(element) {
    return $("input[name='country'],[value='ca'],:checked")
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm using @Tatu Ulmanen's code, however I'm receiving the following error after clicking outside of one of the fields that should be required when "Canada" is checked. Any ideas?

```
province: {
    depends: function(element) {
        return $("input[name='country'][value='ca']").is(':checked')
    }
},
```

> $.validator.methods[method] is
>   undefined [Break On This Error]
>   eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(...x5b|trigger|x21|x23'.split('|'),0,{}))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check of specific radio button is checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195125/check-of-specific-radio-button-is-checked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input[name='country'][value='ca']").is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.is()` method:

```
$("input[name='country'][value='ca']").is(':checked');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried out your code, but am getting an error. See above for my update.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[name='country'],[value='ca']").is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a way:

```
if ($('#id').is(':checked')) {
alert('button is checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as using `.is()`, jQuery 1.6 introduced [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), see 
 http://api.jquery.com/prop/ for details.