# Linking webpages using radio button in HTML

Tags: html, web, hyperlink, radio-button

I have two web pages A and B. Webpage A contains some radio buttons. I just want that if the user selects any of the radio button, webpage B should be opened.

Can anyone help me regarding what should I try to do this?

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript. Side note: using radio buttons for redirecting to a web page is not so user friendly and the intention of the [radio buttons is another](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html). There are anchor elements (links) for redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML alone is not enough. You will need to start learning JavaScript (and preferably jQuery as well).

Assuming you have [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<input type="radio" name="mything" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="mything" value="0"/>

$('input:radio[name="mything"]').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == '1') {
            window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
        }
        else{
            window.location = "http://www.yourotherurl.com";
        }
    });
```

Javascript redirect: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Radio Button selected: [Jquery If radio button is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654601/jquery-if-radio-button-is-checked)

Answer (score 2):

Your need to add the `onclick` attribute to your radiobuttons in this way:

```
<input type='radio' onclick='functionCalled()' />
```

Then under the radio buttons add:

```
<script>
     function functionCalled() {
          window.open(url); //if you want to open in new window
          window.location = url; //if you want to redirect
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" onchange="window.location.replace('URL_OF_WEBSITE')">
```