# Dynamically Remove a Form Element Based on User Selection in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, element

I am trying to remove the option to upload a file upon the selection of the No radio button but when I click No it doesn't go away. I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to JavaScript. How do I make it go away (or come back).

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" required /><br>
        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
        <input class="lname" type="text" required/><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="email" type="text" required/><br>
        <input type="radio" name="file" value="yes" id="yes" />
        <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="file" value="no" id="no" />
        <label for="No" "removeElement();">No</label><br>
        <p><input type="file" size="30" required></p>
        </form>

        <script>
            function validateForm() {
                window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
            }

            function removeElement(){
                var parent = document.getId(file);
                parent.removeChild(file);
            }
        </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using jQuery and Bootstrap?

Comment: @GabrielBourgault I honestly have no idea, I'm using what you see above. I think its just hard-coded java script on an HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put `removeElement();` in the middle of the html tag.

I'm assuming you want to hide the file tag? You'll first want to remove the `required`.

You will need to add an event listener on your No.

In jQuery this looks like this

```
$('#no').change(
    function() {
       if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'no') {
            $(this).hide(); //Change this for the id of the element you want
        }
        else {
            $(this).show(); //Change this for the id of the element you want
        }
    });
```

Partly inspired by [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654640/6316091)

If you're looking for pure JavaScript, here's what my solution would look like :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
<label for="fname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" required /><br>
<label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
<input class="lname" type="text" required/><br>
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input class="email" type="text" required/><br>
<input type="radio" name="file" value="yes" id="yes" onclick="handleChange(false);" />
<label for="Yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="file" value="no" id="no" onclick="handleChange(true);" />
<label for="No">No</label><br>
<p><input type="file" size="30" id="fileUpload"></p>
</form>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
        window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
    }

    function handleChange(remove) {
        var element = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
        if (remove)
            element.style.display = 'none';
        else 
            element.style.display = 'block';
    }

</script>
```

(Not tested)

Comment: this jquery is not vanilla javascript ...:(

Comment: @GabrielBourgault is there a regular JavaScript alternative to this?

Comment: @Noah210012 for sure there is, I can put something up

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for hide:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]').style.display = 'none';
```

for show:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]').style.display = 'block'; //or ''
```

Comment: This goes in the JavaScript?

Comment: insert in function removeElement()

Comment: Thank you so much! What should I put in the HTML? or should I leave it as is?

Comment: This solution will not work out of the box, because you have errors in the HTML.